# Value of type NSSet has no member image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a core data app  using xcode 8.3.2 can't figure out what I am missing hopefully I am providing enough context to explain here [image: xcdatamodel]

in my tableview custom cell class

```
class CustomerCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var thumb: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var phone: UILabel!

func configureCell(customer: Customer) {
    name.text = customer.name
    address.text = customer.address
    phone.text = customer.phone
    thumb.image = customer.toImage?.image as?  //error UIImage Value of type NSSet has no member image
}
```

}
  in my savePressed action relevant code is
        `let picture = Image(context: context)
        picture.image = image.image`
        customer.toImage = picture /error UIImage Value of type NSSet has 
        no member image

```
    ad.saveContext()
```

my loading function `func loadItemData () {

```
    if let item = customerToEdit {

        name.text = item.name
        price.text = "\(item.price)"
        detaile.text = item.details
        image.image = item.toImage?.image as UIImage//errorUIImageValue of type NSSet has no member image

        address.text = item.address
        phone.text = item.phone
        email.text = item.email
        hearAbout.text = item.how
        howMany.text = item.howMany
        howOften.text = item.howoften   
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Which line gives you the error and of which type is `Image.image`

Comment: Sorry I edited to show where errors the thumbImg is of type UIImageView Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

In your model, the `toImage` relationship from `Customer` to `Image` is defined as to-many, and so is represented as an `NSSet`.  But your code treats it as though it is a to-one relationship.  Hence the error: `NSSet` does not have an `image` property.

Amend your model to make it to-one, unless you want each Customer to have multiple related `Image` objects?

Comment: You beat me to it, by seconds! :)

Comment: This is making some more sense now I will try that thanks for looking

Comment: @DuncanC I couldn't decide whether to propose changing the model, or changing the code.  Hopefully between us we've covered the bases. :)

Comment: I changed the relationship killed 2 errors but still getting 1 in my CustomersCell class img.image = customer.toImage?.image as? UIImage

Comment: Is that because of type?

Comment: @MikeHaslam What type is the `image` attribute of `Image`?

Comment: Thanks to all for helping have to run out so I will have to fix this later maybe a little time will clear my mind

Answer (score 0):

Your "toImage" relationship is a "to many" relationship. That is represented as a set. You need to fetch the objects from the set and act on each of them.

Comment: Thanks for looking trying to wrap my head around this